# Regex to find if a url has a tail of a file name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex that will tell me whether a url has an extension of a file name. like (.jpg, .gif, .js etc).

I am ready for a rough rule,

```
"If a string having a dot (.) in any of last (tail) 5 characters its a url with file extension."
```

I am looking the answer in context of javascript.

I went [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

But not able to find a suitable answer.

EDIT : I am certainly not looking for answer of "indexOf()"

Comment: It's probably unlikely that the URL would contain .jpg elsewhere, so why not just use indexOf ?

Comment: not looking for indexOf answers.. looking for a pure regex

Comment: `/(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)/.test(url)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dot followed by 1-4 alphanumeric (or _) chars before the end of the string;

```
/\.\w{1,4}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `myString.slice(-5).indexOf(".") === -1`, regex would be overkill for what you've described.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\.[^.]{1,4}$
```

...SO wants 30 chars for an answer...

Answer (score 0):

`\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` should be the only correct RegEx solution.